# Email notifications to AD group members - no access to Exchange

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, groups, exchange-server

Using SharePoint Designer 2010, I created a group and had AD group as a member. I tried to send email notification to the individuals in that AD group but the email only received by the group email address. I'm trying to make it distributed to the individuals email addresses within the group with no luck. I looked up and found several solutions require changes in Exchange which I don't have access to. Is there any other solution?

Comment: did you created the SharePoint Group and then add AD group in it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the group in SharePoint and send de email to the SharePoint Group.

Let me explain. Understanding that you can not configure Exchange, I think there is no solution using AD groups. The alternative I propose is: create native sharepoint groups and associate users directly to SharePoint groups.

I know that probably you prefer to manage AD groups but not think you can solve it if you do not have access to Exchange.

Comment: Shadin, already mentioned he did and no result, also this is not right answer.could you please edit it and provide him relevant answer.

Comment: Edited. Mi idea is use sharepoint groups with users directly inside, without ad groups.

Comment: Thank you both! Now I can stop looking and move on thinking of another solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known limitation related to send SPD workflow e-mails to AD groups.
Basically AD groups are seen by SPD as a regular user... let's remember that AD groups have properties like e-mail, name, login and everything else.

So, the SPD can't understand that you are trying to send e-mails to everyone inside that group. What you can do is create something that iterates through every user inside that AD group... but this solution goes to the custom .NET way of living.

By the other hand, SPD knows that a SharePoint group is A GROUP. And when you send e-mail to the group, the SPD will send it to everyone inside it.

Comment: I see, thanks for your explanation. I have multiple sub-site which make creating separate groups for each one a painful task, moreover, the process of updating these groups manually whenever needed is not ideal. They better be associated and synchronized with AD. It's strange that SharePoint has such limitation.